# Why using vuex is mapState being stored in computed instead of data?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I just viped out a really quick simple demo using vuex + Vue.js and so i have the below store code as of now:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      title : 'I am the title ! Tanos avengers: End game !',
      links : [
        'http://amazon.com',
        'http://google.com',
        'http://flipkart.com',
      ]
  },
  getters : {
    countLinks : state => {
      return state.links.length;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_LINK : ( state , link ) => {
      state.links.push( link );
    }
  }
});
```

Now when i'am using this store and importing the state in a component i do the following :

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
```

and the inside the `computed` property of the component :-

```
computed : {
    ...mapState({ 
      title : 'title', 
      links : 'links' 
    })
},
```

But why is `...mapState` being put inside `computed` instead of `data` ? is't data where all the properties related to a component should be stored ?

Answer (score 1):

So a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) is basically any property related to the component that isn't just a straightforward piece of information stored in memory, like a string or number or a JS object.

Since Vue has to go into Vuex and check what this.$store.state.title is, that counts as a computation, which makes it a computed property, even though you aren't implementing the computation yourself like in the examples on the Vue guide.